# Mysql COUNT by date only part of DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

```
 +-----+--------------+---------------------+
 | id  | url          | visit_date          | 
 +-----+--------------+---------------------+
 |  1  + 60           | 2012-06-23 18:15:49 |  
 +-----+--------------+---------------------+
 |  2  + 60&ref=qr    | 2012-06-23 12:15:49 |  
 +-----+--------------+---------------------+
 |  3  + 54           | 2012-06-23 18:15:49 |  
 +-----+--------------+---------------------+
 |  4  + 5            | 2012-06-24 18:15:49 |  
 +-----+--------------+---------------------+
 |  5  + 60           | 2012-06-25 13:15:49 |  
 +-----+--------------+---------------------+
 |  6  + 60           | 2012-06-25 19:15:49 |  
 +-----+--------------+---------------------+
```

I want to group results my date only. so the result would be if for example I only wanted url with 60.

```
  +-------------+------------------+
  |visit_date   |count(visit_date) |
  +-------------+------------------+
  |  2012-06-23 |        2         | 
  +-------------+------------------+
  |  2012-06-25 |        2         |
  +-------------+------------------+
```

I have tried the following but obviously I get every date due to the time difference.

```
  SELECT visit_time, COUNT( visit_time ) 
  FROM tracking
  WHERE query_string LIKE  '%60%'
  GROUP BY visit_time
```

is it possible to do this only by the date ignoring the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just use `DATE()` function.

```
SELECT DATE(visit_time), COUNT( visit_time ) 
FROM tracking
WHERE query_string LIKE  CONCAT('%', '60' ,'%')  -- makes readable
GROUP BY DATE(visit_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
GROUP BY date(visit_time)
```