# PHP and MYSQLi Order by most popular items from today?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have data in my table like following:

```
stuff    stuff    stuff    stuff    date_viewed
whtever  whtever  whtever  whtever  2018-05-15 20:58:31
whtever  whtever  whtever  whtever  2018-05-13 15:32:22
whtever  whtever  whtever  whtever  2018-05-15 23:58:44
whtever  whtever  whtever  whtever  2018-05-05 13:21:32
whtever  whtever  whtever  whtever  2018-05-12 13:21:32
whtever  whtever  whtever  whtever  2018-05-14 12:21:32
whtever  whtever  whtever  whtever  #more dates from today and other days...
```

I need to order items from today, but by most popular ones, for example:

Item( today views 20 )

Item2( today views 18 )

Item3( today views 14 )

so on...

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: get a count of date viewed, order by that count, then order by date_viewed again

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the table name? What is `stuff`? What is the datatype for `date_viewed`? Is it nullable? ...

Comment: What have you tried yet? What does your table look like (fieldnames, etc)? You can't expect help without putting effort in it yourself or without showing your effort.

Comment: @waterloomatt, and the other guy. Other data doesn't matter in my question. It's not nullable.

Comment: Of course, it matters. What happens if all the rows are null except for `date_viewed`? You have not given us half of the information we need. Please update your question or it'll be flagged for deletion.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963637/296555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplification I assume that the table is named `table` and only has the two columns `stuff` (some kind of ID or string or whatever you have) and the column `date_viewed` which contains the date and time of the view.

In this case, you query could look like this:

```
SELECT stuff, DATE(date_viewed), COUNT(*) AS views FROM `table`
GROUP BY stuff, DATE(date_viewed)
ORDER BY views DESC
```

What is the query doing?
* It selects `stuff`, together with the [date part](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) of `date_viewed`, and a count of rows calculated by the [COUNT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/counting-rows.html) and stored under the alias (`AS`) name `views` from the `table`.
* The result is then grouped by `stuff` and the `date`, i.e. all entries with the same item ("stuff") and date are put into one result row and the `views` hold the number of original rows.
* Finally, the result is sorted by (`ORDER BY`) number of views (`views`, which was an alias for `COUNT(*)`) in descending order (`DESC`), so that rows with most views go first.

Comment: Thanks you mate, this is how `$sql` looked like 

`"SELECT DATE(date_viewed), movie_id, COUNT(*) AS views FROM visitors WHERE date_viewed = '$today' GROUP BY movie_id ORDER BY views DESC;"`

Comment: All tho I don't understand GROUP BY condition yet, but query worked :$ 
Btw Im new to databases as you would guess. Thanks once again.